# Why redis not first load rdb file before load aof file when start?

Tags: redis

rdb files have *snap* info and *append* info.

So why does redis not first load rdb file, then load rdb command after rdb file?

The load code: [loadDataFromDisk](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/server.c#L3845)

Comment: "why some software has some implementation" is not an on-topic question for SO, this should be addressed to the authors of redis. Since they use github, just create a new issue (well, if they allow to use issues for questions; otherwise find what is the proper way to contact them)

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

From [Redis doc](https://redis.io/topics/persistence):

> It is possible to combine both AOF and RDB in the same instance. Notice that, in this case, when Redis restarts the AOF file will be used to reconstruct the original dataset **since it is guaranteed to be the most complete**.